# Solaris pkgadd environment variables

Tags: unix, solaris, packaging

I've got this package that I install using pkgadd onto Solaris unix. When the package is going through installation I want it to ask for the users username/password or use environment variables set outside of pkgadd. Is this possible to do?

Comment: but you install packages as superuser. When you're superuser, what would you need the password for? Whatever it is, if it needs to store the superuser password, it's *probably* (few exceptions) making a few bad design decisions.

Comment: I'm dealing with a legacy system and when we install secrets are retrieved from vault. However, I need vault credentials setup outside the installation which can be called upon when needed.

Comment: ah that sounds pretty sensible, then.

Answer (score 0):

You can check `preinstall` script and modify, based on your requirements. For more information you can check [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/E28550/ch6advtech-41.html) about.